# Get user's gender on Instagram

Tags: instagram

I just wonder whether there's a way to get user's gender on instagram... I walked through instagram's api and for user's info got from users/userId doesn't include the gender info.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: There is more information about how to get user's gender on instagram with machine learning https://totems.co/blog/machine-learning-nodejs-gender-instagram/

Answer (score 6):

**NO**, there is currently no way to get the gender of the instagram user from API

Answer (score 0):

Instagram API does not work, they do not allow this anymore.
The thing you can do, is to **scrape** name of the user and then determine gender based on name. There is Python lib for this, you can find it here: https://pypi.org/project/gender/