# How To Find The Gender Of An Instagram User

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I was wondering if I can find the gender of an Instagram user through the API.

The only way I thought that information would be displayed is by this endpoint:

https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}

Any input or pointers would be great!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get user's gender on Instagram](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21298462/get-users-gender-on-instagram)

Comment: Instagram API does not work, they do not allow this anymore.
The thing you can do, is to scrap name of the user and then determine gender based on name. There is Python lib for this, you can find it here: https://pypi.org/project/gender/